# How to use Gitlab Helm chart without certmanager and have the registry also work

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

We're trying to set up a gitlab instance on our VPC contained K8S cluster. Because we cannot use the certmanager (and because we have a number of services running already), we've disabled a few services. Below is our configuration which we apply via terraform.

```
global:
  hosts:
    domain: ${var.hosted_zone}
    https: false
    gitlab:
      name: gitlab.${var.hosted_zone}
      https: false
    registry:
      https: false
  ingress:
    tls:
      enabled: false
    configureCertmanager: false

certmanager:
  install: false
prometheus:
  install: false
nginx-ingress:
  enabled: false
postgresql.install: ${var.managed_postgres == true ? "false" : "true"}

registry:
  ingress:
    tls:
      enabled: false
```

Gitlab works, hence the DB connection, gitaly and unicorn work. However, autodevops is giving us trouble. Concretely, the registry is giving us TLS errors. We've tried to disable its TLS as well but haven't succeeded so far

```
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.dev.foo.com/v2/: remote error: tls: internal error
```

There are no logs on the registry pods unfortunately. How would one go about getting the registry to work?